# BubbleSorting C language

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

We are learning arrays and I just came around bubble sorting.
I wrote the following code to sort the array in ascending order but there is a problem.
I can't find it out but I know there's a problem.
I have found the correct code but I still don't understand why this is not working.

**My Code**

```
int a;
int i;

int temp;
int value[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (value[i] > value[i + 1]) {
        temp = value[i];
        value[i] = value[i + 1];
        value[i + 1] = temp;
    }
}

for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    printf(" %d ", value[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hint: you need an inner `for` loop inside your current one to implement bubble sort properly.

Comment: Be careful not compare against an out-of-range item. (That happens now in your code.)

Comment: Moreover, in the last loop, you should use value[ **a** ].

Comment: What do I need an inner for loop?

Comment: See Below Answer , basically you have to run loop multiple times , also you are printing wrong , using **a** for loop  , but printing value[**i**] , instead use value[**a**]

Comment: To paraphrase Shakespeare, "Get thee to a debugger - go! And if thou must debug, debug thine own code, for wise men know well what problems you put into it. To a debugger go, and quickly too. Farewell!". In other words, if you want to be a software developer you need to actually sit down with the code you've written and make it work. Writing broken code is not a marketable skill - you need to make it work. Best of luck.

Comment: Did the answer Worked For You ?

Comment: Yes thank you It helped alot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Code Has Multiple Problems ,

1. First And Foremost You are printing the array elements after that sorting that you did with `value[i]` and you are running loop with variable `a`.

   ```
   for(a=0;a<5;a++){               //You Are Incrementing a

   printf(" %d ",value[i]);        //But Using i here , change it to a.
                                   //As It will just print the value[i] member

   }
   ```
2. You are Accessing `value[5]` , which is not yours.

   ```
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){ //Here In The Last Loop value[4] is  compared with value[5],
                      // value[5] is not defined 

   //for(i=0;i<4;i++)       
   //Instead Run Loop Till i<4 , I guess this is what you 
   //wanted but accidently made a mistake.

      if(value[i]>value[i+1])
   ```
3. The Biggest Problem, is that you have not understood Bubblesort completely.
   In Bubble Sort The Loop is run multiple times, until in a loop there are no       member to swap, that is when you stop looping.

This is What Wikipedia [Says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

> **Bubble sort**, sometimes referred to as **sinking sort**, is a simple sorting algorithm that repeatedly steps through the list to be sorted, compares each pair of adjacent items and swaps them if they are in the wrong order. The pass through the list is repeated until no swaps are needed, which indicates that the list is sorted. The algorithm, which is a comparison sort, is named for the way smaller or larger elements "bubble" to the top of the list. Although the algorithm is simple, it is too slow and impractical for most problems even when compared to insertion sort.It can be practical if the input is usually in sorted order but may occasionally have some out-of-order elements nearly in position.

See The Below Presentation To Understand How Bubble Sort Works.See the Loop Run again and again, till there are no member left to swap.

[image]

> **Step-by-step example**
>
> Let us take the array of numbers "5 1 4 2 8", and sort the array from lowest number to greatest number using bubble sort. In each step, elements written in **bold** are being compared. Three passes will be required.
>
> **First Pass**
>
> ( **5 1** 4 2 8 ) to ( **1 5** 4 2 8 ), Here algorithm compares the first 2  elements,and swap since 5 > 1.
>    ( 1 **5 4** 2 8 ) to ( 1 **4 5** 2 8 ), Swap since 5 > 4
>    ( 1 4 **5 2** 8 ) to ( 1 4 **2 5** 8 ), Swap since 5 > 2
>    ( 1 4 2 **5 8** ) to ( 1 4 2 **5 8** ), Now, since these elements are already in order (8 > 5), algorithm does not swap them.
>
> **Second Pass**
>
> ( **1 4** 2 5 8 ) to ( **1 4** 2 5 8 )
>    ( 1 **4 2** 5 8 ) to ( 1 **2 4** 5 8 ), Swap since 4 > 2
>    ( 1 2 **4 5** 8 ) to ( 1 2 **4 5** 8 )
>    ( 1 2 4 **5 8** ) to ( 1 2 4 **5 8** )
>
> Now, the array is already sorted, but the algorithm does not know if it is completed. The algorithm needs one whole pass without any swap to know it is sorted.
>
> **Third Pass**
>
> ( **1 2** 4 5 8 ) to  ( **1 2** 4 5 8 )
>    ( 1 **2 4** 5 8 ) to  ( 1 **2 4** 5 8 )
>    ( 1 2 **4 5** 8 ) to  ( 1 2 **4 5** 8 )
>    ( 1 2 4 **5 8** ) to  ( 1 2 4 **5 8** )

So You Need To Run The Loop Multiple Times Until No Member Are There To Swap, You Can Do So By Having a new variable `count`, initially initialised to `1` at the start, and before each loop starts, it get initialised to `0`, if in the loop, Swap statement executes then, it changes to `1`, and again the loop is executed because count is `1`, if in the last pass, its value does not changes to `1` because all member are now sorted, so loop does not run again.

Comment: @WaqasShahbaz You Could Upvote it, if it helped you.

Comment: @WaqasShahbaz Everything In Yellow was from wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

When `i == 4` you access the position **5** with `value[i+1]` and it is not yours.

You are accessing unreserved memory.