# C Programm.How can I sort the RANDOM List in C?

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm suppose to sort a list with random 5 numbers. They also gave me a ready list to check if it is working. The random list have to sort the number that is the smallest in the list and put it on the first array of the list and then on second and third... till it's sorted.
I don't know why it's not working... please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void generate_randomzahlen(int *a, int *n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 5;
        printf("%d\n", &a[i]);
    }
}

void setMINAdressIfMinIsGreater(int *min, int *arr) {
    if (*min > *arr) {
        *min = arr;
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    printf("Anfang A: %d, Anfang B: %d\n", *a, *b);
    int text_a = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = text_a;
    printf("A danach: %d, B danach: %d\n", *a, *b);

void selektionsSort(int arr[], int length) {
    int *cur;
    int *min;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cur = &arr[i];
        min = &arr[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            setMINAdressIfMinIsGreater(&min, &arr[j]);
        }
        swap(cur, min); //Array der kleiner ist wird dann am Anfang von meine Liste
    }
}

int main() {
    //Checking ob es richtig ist
    int array[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int liste = array;
    printf("Die erste Liste: %d\t", liste);

    printf("Sortierung von der Liste: \n");
    selektionsSort(array, 5);//(array[],length von Liste);

    int n, i;
    printf("\n Wie viele zufallige Zahlen soll dieser Array haben?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    generate_randomzahlen(a, n);

    printf("\nZufallige Liste: ");
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        printf("d", a[i]);
    }

    selektionsSort(a[i], n);
    printf("Richtige Liste: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        printf("\n \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int liste = array;` ==> `int liste = array[0];`

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043489/bubblesorting-c-language

Comment: Post the input you pass to the program and its output.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in function declaration :

```
void generate_randomzahlen (int * a, int * n) // declare n as a pointer
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){ // use n as a value so result is undetermined
        a[i]=rand()%5;
        printf("%d\n",&a[i]);
    }
}
```

you should change declaration to :

```
void generate_randomzahlen (int * a, int n) // declare n as a int
```